# MSSQL Complex Query with Foearch and Calculations

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

In a new project i need to select content based on the users interests. As i want to do that in a SQL Query (i guess this should be more performant?) i want to to something like this:

I have a table called 'content'. This table has a id and content. Then i have a table called tags, which has an id, name and content_id (to reverence to the content table)

Now i want to calculate something like a "score" for each content, which matches the content tags against the users interest tags. I think this could be done something like:
Iterating through the content, matching all tags with the users interest tags and then if there's a match add +10 to the score. At the end sort it by score and done.

Is this even possible in MSSQL? Thank's in advice!

Comment: Sounds like it's possible. The key point to understand is that SQL works on sets of data, so if you select out a set, you can aggregate values across that set without iterating. So instead of thinking just 'line based iterations', think 'sets of data' and aggregations.

Comment: Thank's for you're comment. I will try to get into that thinking.